# Connecting with another Oracle user within the Oracle Apex platform

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have access to that user in SQL Developer. How can I access this same user in Apex, to make any query?

Answer (score 0):

Talk to your Apex admin. They should *map* that schema (i.e. user with all its objects) to your workspace.

Alternatively, you could create a database link from your current user (the one you already use in Apex) to the one that contains data you're interested in. Then you could access data over that database link, perhaps create synonyms in your schema (to make it simpler). Though, I'd probably go for the 1st option I suggested.

---

But, if you don't use Apex yet, then - back to Apex admin again; they should create a workspace for you, let you use schema you're talking about, create an Apex developer for you and - that should do it.